# effects of scroll view delegate methods on tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, crash-reports

I am trying play with all the methods on `protocol` methods of `UIScrollViewDelegate` on a `tableview`, things work fine but two issues

1. the scrolling is not smooth, it stubs in between, could be because of large cells (heights are like 80px.
2. Crash, very rarely happens but could not figure out the reason behind the issue

Please help me to find out the reasons for both the issues.thanks.

> Date/Time:       2013-07-25 17:20:41.675 -0700 OS Version:      iPhone
>   OS 5.1 (9B176) Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000008 Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib                  0x37ed7f78 objc_msgSend +
>   16 1   UIKit                          0x32aa573e -[UIGestureRecognizer
>   setState:] + 206 2   UIKit                            0x32af86c4
>   -[UILongPressGestureRecognizer enoughTimeElapsed:] + 132 3   CoreFoundation                   0x3366e1f4 -[NSObject
>   performSelector:withObject:] + 36 4   UIKit
>     0x32a9f1fe -[UIDelayedAction timerFired:] + 74 5   Foundation
>     0x37d4f606 **NSFireTimer + 138 6   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x336e3a2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**
>   + 8 7   CoreFoundation                    0x336e3692 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 358 8   CoreFoundation                  0x336e2268 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1200 9   CoreFoundation                   0x3366549e
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294 10  CoreFoundation
>     0x33665366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98 11  GraphicsServices
>     0x36a19432 GSEventRunModal + 130 12  UIKit
>     0x329d2e76 UIApplicationMain + 1074

Comment: In terms of the sluggish performance, I can only guess. It is either the resources that you are trying to display or the way you are doing it. For example, if you have are displaying heavy images or there is a lot of work happening in a custom draw rect of the `TableCellView`.

Comment: You need to post the code that caused this error.

Comment: @rdelmar actually the crash is not pointed to any lines of code on my app, it is pointing to uikit classes

Comment: You still need to post your code (everything in the table view's data source and delegate).

Comment: atlast i found the reason for the issue, sorry i couldnt post the code.

Comment: The reason for the crash is due to memory, there was a small glitch which was stopping reusable identifiers properly, it was creating fresh instances everytime. Now it is fixed.